# FFmpeg - Converting mkv to mp4 with surround sound

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, matroska, 5.1

I've searched many posts about this topic, and still cant get this done.

To be exact, I'm trying to convert .mkv file with subtitles and surround sound to .mp4 with embedded subtitles and with as hi quality of sound and video, as my TV can handle(Samsung Q70).

Previously I was using this script:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i "%~1" -vf scale=1920:1080,format=yuv420p,subtitles="%~n1.mkv" -profile:v main -level 4.0 -preset veryslow -crf 15 "%~n1.mp4"
```

It have satisfied video and sound quality but audio channels were messed up.

Comment: Try using the -map flag to individually map your audio streams. This might be a suitable way to repair your previous command.

Comment: Show the full log from your command.

Comment: @llogan

I have problems with cmd to cooperate, but here it is
https://pastebin.com/QS6yzJqE

Also I added to script to convert only 10 seconds to safe the time.

Comment: @johnbchron I don't fully understand ffmpeg commands, but mapping isn't' possible only when It has separate audio tracks?

Comment: Nope. With the map command, you specify the input file, optionally only video or audio streams, and the index of the stream. So you could use your map command like `-map 0:a:1 -map 0:a:0 -map 1:1` to get the second audio stream from the first file, then the first audio stream from the first file, then the second stream in the second file, in that order. Map flags are very powerful and flexible

Comment: @pawlo444444 *"audio channels were messed up."* Can you explain in more detail what is wrong with the audio channels?

Comment: @llogan So maybe I will start from the beginning. My setup for watching is as I said earlier TV(Samsung Q70), and for the audio I have soundbar Yamaha YSP2700.

With my script, films watched with stereo mode are OK, at least I didn't noticed anything wrong with the audio. But when I switch to the surround mode(5.1), the left side appears louder and it plays more stuff like dialogues, and the left side seems dully.

Comment: @llogan Just a couple minutes ago I found test samples for Dolby Digital 7.1, DTS 7.1 and DTS 5.1. As I noticed on normal content, here the left side was also much more noticeable, when the right one was really separated and accurate.  Also Dolby didn't plays the right, and left surround channels, and DTS didn't played right and left rear surround channel.

Comment: This last comment makes me think that the issue has nothing to do with ffmpeg.

Comment: @llogan I was wondering how the channels look so I've used Audiacity to see if after encoding channels were mixed with each other, but to my surprise it looked the same... Even compared Dolby and DTS where some channels were missing, on audiacity there ware all, and not only that. By looking at the channels layout it looks like the Dolby and DTS are the same, but on my TV in one time channel were missing, even when physical I have L&R rear surround seekers. Only channels that shouldn't appear are L&R surround. I don't get it any more. On content with 5.1 audio(Netflix) works normal.

Comment: @llogan Here I uploaded converted version of  the DTS 5.1 channel sample, might by You will notice, if something is wrong with this. 

Also I forgot about this, but when I convert video with stereo channels it will convert to 5.1 channels.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1L8UttadNY5u6zi_NPSa3k6nz4NhINWE_/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

At the end I didn't found a answer to my question, but I resolve my problem by doing this differently. I used "Pazera Free Audio Extractor" to extract and convert original audio to AC3 format, then when the video will convert I added converted audio with "mkvtoolnix". In that way it worked perfectly.